# Mapping ctrl+shift+something to do something in zsh with urxvt

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, rxvt

For example in my `.Xresources` I have a line `URxvt.keysym.Control-Left: \033[1;5C`. I don't know very well  what `\033[1;5C` means, but by having `bindkey "^[[1;5C" forward-word` in my `.zshrc` it allows me to walk left a word in terminal which is useful.

Because I use vim, I wanted to map ctrl+w to delete a "word" and ctrl+shift+w to delete a "WORD". If I add `URxvt.keysym.C-W: something` in `.Xresources` , pressing ctrl+shift+w will write `something`. What can I put in that something? I'm thinking maybe I should put some symbols like `\033[1;5C` so I can refer to them in `.zshrc`, but I don't know what those symbols mean and don't want to bind some wrong key combination and press it by accident.

So what does something of the form `\033[1;5C` mean and where can I read about it? And what can I put so it doesn't conflict?

Answer (score 1):

It has no meaning for rxvt/urxvt, but is copied from xterm's [alt/meta key](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Alt-and-Meta-Keys) definitions.  In that context, it means <kbd>*control*</kbd><kbd>*Right-cursor*</kbd>:

```
                Code     Modifiers
              ---------+---------------------------
                 2     | Shift
                 3     | Alt
                 4     | Shift + Alt
                 5     | Control
                 6     | Shift + Control
                 7     | Alt + Control
                 8     | Shift + Alt + Control
                 9     | Meta
                 10    | Meta + Shift
                 11    | Meta + Alt
                 12    | Meta + Alt + Shift
                 13    | Meta + Ctrl
                 14    | Meta + Ctrl + Shift
                 15    | Meta + Ctrl + Alt
                 16    | Meta + Ctrl + Alt + Shift
              ---------+---------------------------

              Key            Normal     Application
              -------------+----------+-------------
              Cursor Up    | CSI A    | SS3 A
              Cursor Down  | CSI B    | SS3 B
              Cursor Right | CSI C    | SS3 C
              Cursor Left  | CSI D    | SS3 D
              -------------+----------+-------------
```